# How to change the text of an option item on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to setup a dropdown list for phone number extensions that would display the extension (just +xxx, e.g. +44), while the dropdown list would contain a more descriptive piece of text, like "United Kingdom (+44)" instead.

I managed to make some headway, but I'm having trouble making the text revert when the dropdown is re-opened with an item selected. And the dropdown will show the correct value, but the list of options will still show the number instead (However, it works fine in firefox, but not chrome/IE at the least)

I would appreciate any help on what can be done to achieve it, preferably while still using the 'standard' input control.

Current Code/jsFiddle:

```
var toggled = 1;
$(function(){
  $("#ddMobileExtension option").each(function () {
    // Set data item for all options
    $(this).data("data-txt", $(this).text());
  });
  $("#ddMobileExtension").change(function () {
    $("option", this).each(function () {
      // Reset all options to their corresponding data items
      $(this).text($(this).data("data-txt"));
    });
    // Set the selected option to be +XX
    // (Provided it's not the first item)
    $(this).find("option:selected").text(
      $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value") != "-1" ? "+" + $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value") : ""
    );
  });

  $("#ddMobileExtension").on("click", function(e){
    if(toggled == 1){
      // On dropdown being opened, set the option text back
      // to the more readable form
      $(e.target).find("option:selected").text($(e.target).find("option:selected").data("data-txt"));
      toggled = 0;
    } else {
      // On dropdown being closed, set the option text back
      // to the +XX format
      $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value") != "-1" ? $(e.target).find("option:selected").text("+" + $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value")) : "";
      toggled = 1;
    }
  }).blur(function(){
    // Catch for tabbing out and back in mid-selection
    toggled = 1;
  });
});


<select ID="ddMobileExtension" style="width:61px">
  <option Value="-1" Text="" />
  <option Value="44">United Kingdom (+44)</option>
  <option Value="1">United States (+1)</option>
  <option Value="1784">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)</option>
  <option Value="976">Mongolia (+976)</option>
</select>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz41rh1n/5/)

Comment: So you want to reset each option on `focus`?

Comment: I see you have Jquery UI enabled in your Fiddle. Are you open to using the Autocomplete option?

Comment: Not necessarily wanting to reset each option on `focus` just a way I was trying to achieve my goal. And preferably wanting to keep it as a dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieve just add and remove `label attribute` in selected `option element`. we should use `mousedown event` to avoid this trouble making the text revert when the dropdown is re-opened with an item selected. It is actually take a time to update in options when use `click event`. check this things in DevTools when clicking select box.
it works fine in firefox, chrome and IE.

Final fixed code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n2muduv/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddMobileExtension").change(function() {
    var label = $(this).find("option:selected")[0].label;
    $($(this).find("option:selected")[0]).attr("label", label.substring(label.indexOf("(") + 1, label.indexOf(")")));
  });
  $("#ddMobileExtension").mousedown(function(e) {
    var rem = document.querySelector('option[label]')
    if (rem) {
      rem.removeAttribute("label")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select ID="ddMobileExtension" style="width:61px">
  <option Value="-1" Text="" />
  <option Value="44">United Kingdom (+44)</option>
  <option Value="1">United States (+1)</option>
  <option Value="1784">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)</option>
  <option Value="976">Mongolia (+976)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Firefox 51.0.1 for me, possibly related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40545

Comment: @L.F yes right. we can fix that bug in different way , see this link https://jsfiddle.net/0n2muduv/3/

Comment: Only problem is it now makes IE not work well; it makes IE de-select the dropdown when you re-open it, so you have to open it twice. But that's easily solvable by adding a check for if the browser is Firefox and then it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do, make use of jQuery UI Autocomplete:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3nxu01vg/4/

**HTML**

```
<input ID="ddMobileExtension" style="width:61px" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var extensions = [{
  label: "United Kingdom (+44)",
  value: 44
}, {
  label: "United States (+1)",
  value: 1
}, {
  label: "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)",
  value: 1784
}, {
  label: "Mongolia (+976)",
  value: 976
}];

$(function() {
  $("#ddMobileExtension").autocomplete({
    source: extensions,
    minLength: 0
  }).click(function() {
    $(this).trigger("keydown");
  });
});
```

This works the way you're describing.

If you do not want to do this, you can do as you propose, by changing the text of `option` once selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3nxu01vg/9/

**HTML**

```
<select ID="ddMobileExtension" style="width:61px">
  <option value="-1"></option>
  <option value="44" data-orig-text="United Kingdom (+44)">United Kingdom (+44)</option>
  <option value="1" data-orig-text="United States (+1)">United States (+1)</option>
  <option value="1784" data-orig-text="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)</option>
  <option value="976" data-orig-text="Mongolia (+976)">Mongolia (+976)</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#ddMobileExtension").focus(function(e) {
    var $items = $(this).find("option");
    $items.each(function(ind, elem) {
      if (ind !== 0) {
        $(elem).html($(elem).data("orig-text"));
      }
    });
  }).change(function(e) {
    var $item = $(this).find(":selected");
    if ($item.index() !== 0) {
      $item.html($item.val());
    }
    $(this).trigger("blur")
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

**Update for IE 8 -> 11**

This code will not operate the same in Internet Explorer. This will operate in Edge.

See More: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2511

> Unfortunately, all versions of IE (even IE 11) fire `blur` & `focus` events asynchronously and there is no easy way to work around it generically enough to include the workaround in jQuery.
>
> Good news is it's fixed in the new Microsoft Edge browser but IE 11 will stay as it is forever.

Comment: Looking at the select based solution it seems to fail in IE unfortunately

Comment: In IE it retains the numeric value for the option text when you re-open the dropdown, instead of showing the text

Comment: So its not executing the `blur` or not firing `focus`. Will see if ie needs something else.

Comment: Found this: *Unfortunately, all versions of IE (even IE 11) fire blur & focus events asynchronously and there is no easy way to work around it generically enough to include the workaround in jQuery. Good news is it's fixed in the new Microsoft Edge browser but IE 11 will stay as it is forever.* See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2511

Comment: I do not see a way to get IE to work the same way: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3nxu01vg/14/ has examples of all the suggested workarounds. It does work in Edge.

Comment: I see, life would simple be too easy if all the browsers worked the same way :) I'll go ahead with Mathankumar K's solution. But thank you for showing a bug of IE I'll likely need to avoid in the future